# Non Active Record Model works in heroku but does not work locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I declare an additional class in the model folder which does not use ActiveRecord.

I try to use that class in another model like that:

```
::ClassName.new
```

But somehow this just works on heroku:

```
 NameError (uninitialized constant ClassName):
```

Locally i need a require 'classname' to make it work which on the other hand does not work on heroku.

Any way to solve this? Why is this behaving differently locally and and on heroku?

Comment: Is it really **directly** inside `app/models`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to **why** this is happening, but thought I'd share one thing I do in my application *(which may also serve to solve your problem)*.

In my `config/application.rb` I put

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

I have a directory structure in `app/models` like

```
- app
  |
   - models
     |
      - database
      - observer
      - tableless
```

I'd place `class_name.rb` into `app/models/tableless`. This helps to group model classes into the "type" of purpose they serve. I've never had a problem using classes with this setup on Heroku.

Comment: It was a naming problem: My class name was TimeSlot and the file was called timeslot.rb. But it has to be time_slot.rb

Comment: Still I really like your way to structure the models

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out; I hope my mention of `class_name.rb` bumped you toward your solution!